# Append integers to a dictionary whose starting values are empty lists

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I have the dictionary `my_dict = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': []}` and am trying to create the following: `my_dict = {'A': [0,3,6], 'B': [1,4,7], 'C': [2,5,8]}`. This is what I have devised to do this:

```
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']

my_dict = dict.fromkeys(labels, [])

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(len(labels)):
        my_dict[labels[i]].append(3*j+i)

print(my_dict)
```

However, `print(my_dict`) gives the following: {'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'C': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Can you also give a solution, in which I can append an arbitrary values to a dictionary, or any data structure with labeled columns as I've done here?

The motivation is I am trying to extract certain variables, e.g. 'labels', from a large dataset where I don't know how many elements are under each label name, hence my wanting to use append.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` in `dict.fromkeys(labels, [])` is run only once, so all the keys refer to the same list.

From the very [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) of `fromkey`: "All of the values refer to just a single instance, so **it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list**. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead."

The list comprehension would look like that:

```
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']

my_dict = {label:[] for label in labels}
```

You could also use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

See the answer by *matszwecja* for reasons why you are getting incorrect output (yes, mutable objects is a frequent "gotcha" in Python).

Instead, use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) with [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
inside it, like so:

```
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C']
my_dict = {labels[i]: [i + 3 * j for j in range(3)] for i in range(len(labels))}
print(my_dict)
# {'A': [0, 3, 6], 'B': [1, 4, 7], 'C': [2, 5, 8]}
```

Note that using comprehensions as shown is faster and more pythonic than using `append` in a loop.